# How do I target only elements with specific text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to target only the LI's with the test "Refundable" and "No deposit required". I understand, in part, why other LI's are also being targeted. But how do I isolate the list to only the parent that contains "Best Flexible Rate"?

```
<div class="regularRates roomsView">
    <div class="rateTypeLineItem "> <span>Advance Purchase</span>

        <ul>
            <li>Non-Refundable</li>
            <li>Deposit required</li>
            <li class="BREAKFAST_TWO_GUESTS">Breakfast included</li>
            <li>Must purchase 14 days in advance</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /end rateTypeLineItem -->
</div>
<!-- /end regularRates/roomsView -->
<div class="regularRates roomsView">
    <div class="rateTypeLineItem "> <span class="groupHeader">Best Flexible Rate</span>

        <ul>
            <li>Refundable</li>
            <li>No deposit required</li>
            <li class="BREAKFAST_TWO_GUESTS">Breakfast included</li>
            <li>Must purchase 14 days in advance</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /end rateTypeLineItem -->
</div>
<!-- /end regularRates/roomsView -->
<div class="regularRates roomsView">
    <div class="rateTypeLineItem "> <span>Staybridge Weekends</span>

        <ul>
            <li>Non-Refundable</li>
            <li>Deposit required</li>
            <li class="BREAKFAST_TWO_GUESTS">Breakfast included</li>
            <li>Must purchase 14 days in advance</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /end rateTypeLineItem -->
</div>
<!-- /end regularRates/roomsView -->
```

Here's a portion of my script:

```
//add color and weight to each best Flex Rate with  LI containing Refundable
jQuery(':contains("Best Flexible Rate") ul li span.refundable').each(function () {
    if (jQuery(this).text().indexOf('Refundable') > -1) {
        jQuery(this).attr('style', '');
        jQuery(this).css({
            'color': '#E37C00',
                'font-weight': 'bold'
        });
    }
});
//add color and weight to each best Flex Rate with  LI containing No Deposit
jQuery(':contains("Best Flexible Rate") ul li span.noDeposit').each(function () {
    if (jQuery(this).text().indexOf('No deposit required') > -1) {
        jQuery(this).attr('style', '');
        jQuery(this).css({
            'color': '#E37C00',
                'font-weight': 'bold'
        });
    }
});
```

You can view the rest here: http://jsfiddle.net/bkmills1/5kjLF/2/

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Just so you know this could be made much more efficient by searching for elements matching `.rateTypeLineItem`, then using filter to identify the divs around your spans using `:contains`, then use `.find('span.noDeposit')` to search for the spans, this sounds more complicated, but actually using `:contains` is really inefficient as jQuery will scan every element in the scope(which you're using the whole page) looking for the content. This version minimises the content to the bare minimum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just change this line:

```
if (jQuery(this).text().indexOf('Refundable') > -1)
```

to this:

```
if (jQuery(this).text().indexOf('Refundable') === 0)
```

and that way it won't match "Non-Refundable" as well.

Comment: So far, this has proven to be the winner! Thanks, Andi!! 

The only problem, however, is that there are scenarios where other lists have the same items (i.e. Refundable, No deposit, etc.). 

So what I did was add the parent class name to the :contains() selector ( jQuery('.rateTypeLineItem:contains("Best Flexible Rate") ). That did the trick!!

Thanks also, scragar. You've definitely got me thinking about your comments/suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to target a

tag that includes this text, be sure to say that in your query or else the parents will also be targeted:

```
jQuery('li:contains("Best Flexible Rate") ul li span.noDeposit')
```

Not sure if that is what you meant by

> But how do I isolate the list to only the parent that contains "Best
>   Flexible Rate"?